# Use GPU-debugger (GAPID) android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, gpu

I am trying to use the new open source GPU debugging tool in Android studio since the earlier version was removed

https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-gpu-debugger.html

So - I went to the SDK-manager and installed GAPID - no problem with that.

But my question - how do I use it then since it should be integrated in Android Studio?

The GPU-rendering profile is already enabled on the device (adb shell dumpsys gfx-info)

All I can see by now is a green timeline in the GPU-debugger

What could be missing/the problem or my missunderstanding?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [GAPID](https://github.com/google/gapid) and [AndroidStudio](https://developer.android.com/studio/) don't mix. Even though GAPID can be installed via the SDK Manager.

As a matter of fact, [they recommend](https://github.com/google/gapid/issues/911) you close AndroidStudio, and make sure it is not running when you want to use GAPID.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what installing it from the SDK Manager does (I can't find a `gapid.exe` on Windows under the `[android-sdk]/extras/android/gapid` folder), but GAPID can be used as a **standalone tool**. You can get it from github: https://github.com/google/gapid/releases.